# Preserve Dataset for single column and single result instead of returning List

Tags: dataset

For consistency I would like the results of Select and similar operation on Datasets to always return a Dataset object.  If you query a Dataset and the result is a single column or a single value a List is returned.

```
data = {{"ID", "Variable1", "Variable2"}, {"Alpha", 1, 0}, {"Beta", 1,1}, {"Alpha", 1, 0}};
assoc = AssociationThread[First@data -> #] & /@ Rest@data;
ds = Dataset[assoc];
```

This returns a Dataset

```
ds[Select[#"ID" == "Alpha" &], {"ID", "Variable1"}]
```

This returns a List

```
ds[Select[#"ID" == "Alpha" &], "ID"]
(* Result {Alpha,Alpha} *)
```

This returns a list

```
ds[Select[#"ID" == "Beta" &], "ID"]
(* Result {Beta} *)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 10.0.2 under Windows all three operations return an object with the [`Head`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Head.html) `Dataset`.  I presume you mean that within this `Dataset` you want `Association` lists rather than plain lists?  Perhaps your goal is achieved with:

```
ds[Select[#"ID" == "Alpha" &], {"ID"}]

ds[Select[#"ID" == "Beta" &], {"ID"}]
```

[image]

Comment: So simple.  Didn't think to check the head - took what I could with my eyes as evidence.  Nicely done.