# Dataset with more than 16 "columns"?

Tags: dataset

A `Dataset` with 16 columns or less is shown in a nice way:

```
Association @@@ 
   Table["col" <> ToString@j -> i j, {i, 10}, {j, 16}] // Dataset
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A Dataset with more than 16 columns no.

```
set = Association @@@ 
   Table["col" <> ToString@j -> i j, {i, 10}, {j, 17}] // Dataset
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

At this point one can guess a proper subset of these 17 columns is shown in a nice way. Indeed:

```
set[All, 1 ;; 2]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Wrong guess :)** But it's "easy" to improve this appearance:

```
set[All, 1 ;; 2] // Normal // Dataset
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Am'I missing something or there is maybe a super-secret option to control this behavior?

Comment: This isn't quite what you want, but you can get a bit of control over how much the `Dataset` typesetting shows by modifying the variable `Dataset\`$ElisionThreshold`. However, that doesn't help here. The problem is that when going from 16 to 17 columns, the deduced type of the data goes from `TypeSystem\`Struct` to `TypeSystem\`Assoc`, which has different typesetting rules (although it probably should be displayed as nicely, perhaps a minor bug?).

Comment: Note that you can inspect the deduced data type by using `Dataset\`GetType`, e.g. `Dataset\`GetType[set]`.

Comment: Also, `Dataset` has an undocumented second argument, where you can explicitly specify the type: `Dataset[data, type]`. So here you could do `Dataset[data, TypeSystem\`Vector[TypeSystem\`Struct[{"col1",...,"col17"}, {TypeSystem\`Atom[Integer],....},10]]`

Comment: This is similar to the question I asked [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/73852/preserve-dataset-for-single-column-and-single-result-instead-of-returning-list).  In this case the answer is not quite as useful but I think its still a minor improvement on what you have.  Basically wrap your selection criteria in braces.  `set[All, {1 ;; 2}]`  if we are lucky @Mr.Wizard will be along shortly to improve it ;)

Comment: @StefanR Consider making this an answer - it looks like a good one (to me at least).

Answer (score 9):

The general "super-secret option" question was addressed by [Stefan R](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5678/stefan-r) in the comments. This is an answer to the practical problem of easily making a particular dataset show in a nice way.

Actually, it is more of a trick, and one which exploits some of the other new *Mathematica* machinery: semantic interpretation. It turns out that *datasets created from semantically imported data are always nicely formatted*, no matter the number of columns. Thus, we can use the old `SemanticImportString`-`ExportString` routine to get a proper display:

```
displaydataset[dataset_] := With[
   {import = SemanticImportString[
      ExportString[ Join[{Normal@dataset[1, Keys]}, Normal@dataset[Values]], "CSV"], 
      Automatic, "Dataset"]},
   import[All, AssociationThread[Normal@dataset[1, Keys], Normal@import[1, Keys]]]
   ];
```

The extra structure in the last line replaces the imported keys with the old keys - imported keys come in garbled if they have any special symbols (like greek letters) in them. The rest of the data should, in most cases, be handled well by the interpreter.

With

```
set = Association @@@ Table["col" <> ToString@j -> i j, {i, 10}, {j, 17}] // Dataset
```

[image: set]

we get

```
displaydataset@set
```

[image: dataset]